# Добавление кнопки в всплывающее окно. JS leaflet

Tags: javascript, всплывающее-окно, qgis

Я создал карту в QGis и с помощью плагина qgis2web экспортировал его. Теперь мне надо добавить кнопку в всплывающее окно, которое открывается при наведении курсора на слой, и сделать так, чтобы при нажатии на кнопку открывалось еще одно окно с информацией о слое. Можно ли вообще так сделать? Можно было бы просто добавить информацию в это всплывающее окно, но мне надо, чтобы это окно было более функциональным (добавить туда таблицы, графики, вкладки и т.д.).

Comment: Ответ можно вас устроит?

Answer (score 0):

Такая форма пойдет? Чтобы кнопки были и работать можно.

```js
$( function() {
    var dialog, form,
 
      emailRegex = /^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$/,
      name = $( "#name" ),
      email = $( "#email" ),
      password = $( "#password" ),
      allFields = $( [] ).add( name ).add( email ).add( password ),
      tips = $( ".validateTips" );
 
    function updateTips( t ) {
      tips
        .text( t )
        .addClass( "ui-state-highlight" );
      setTimeout(function() {
        tips.removeClass( "ui-state-highlight", 1500 );
      }, 500 );
    }
 
    function checkLength( o, n, min, max ) {
      if ( o.val().length > max || o.val().length < min ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( "Length of " + n + " must be between " +
          min + " and " + max + "." );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
 
    function checkRegexp( o, regexp, n ) {
      if ( !( regexp.test( o.val() ) ) ) {
        o.addClass( "ui-state-error" );
        updateTips( n );
        return false;
      } else {
        return true;
      }
    }
 
    function addUser() {
      var valid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
 
      valid = valid && checkLength( name, "username", 3, 16 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( email, "email", 6, 80 );
      valid = valid && checkLength( password, "password", 5, 16 );
 
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( name, /^[a-z]([0-9a-z_\s])+$/i, "Username may consist of a-z, 0-9, underscores, spaces and must begin with a letter." );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( email, emailRegex, "eg. ui@jquery.com" );
      valid = valid && checkRegexp( password, /^([0-9a-zA-Z])+$/, "Password field only allow : a-z 0-9" );
 
      if ( valid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + name.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + email.val() + "</td>" +
          "<td>" + password.val() + "</td>" +
        "</tr>" );
        dialog.dialog( "close" );
      }
      return valid;
    }
 
    dialog = $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
      autoOpen: false,
      height: 400,
      width: 350,
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        "Create an account": function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        },
        Cancel: function() {
          dialog.dialog( "close" );
        }
      },
      close: function() {
        form[ 0 ].reset();
        allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
      }
    });
 
    form = dialog.find( "form" ).on( "submit", function( event ) {
      event.preventDefault();      
    });
 
    $( "#create-user" ).button().on( "click", function() {
      dialog.dialog( "open" );
    });
  } );
```

```css
label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/resources/demos/style.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
  
<div id="dialog-form" title="Create new user">
  <p class="validateTips">All form fields are required.</p>
 
  <form>
    <fieldset>
      <div>Мне не мешает ничего менять форму так ка я хочу</div>
      <label for="name">Сюда можно что-то ввести</label>
  <input type="text" name="name" id="name" value="Jane Smith" class="text ui-widget-content ui-corner-all">
      <table style="width:100%">
        <tr>
      <th>Firstname</th>
      <th>Lastname</th>
      <th>Age</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Jill</td>
      <td>Smith</td>
      <td>50</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
      <td>Eve</td>
      <td>Jackson</td>
      <td>94</td>
        </tr>
      </table>
      <input type="submit" tabindex="-1" style="position:absolute; top:-1000px">
    </fieldset>
  </form>
</div>
 
 
<div id="users-contain" class="ui-widget">
  <h1>Existing Users:</h1>
  <table id="users" class="ui-widget ui-widget-content">
    <thead>
      <tr class="ui-widget-header ">
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Email</th>
        <th>Password</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>john.doe@example.com</td>
        <td>johndoe1</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<button id="create-user">Create new user</button>
```

Comment: Aziz, у Вас я так понимаю при открытии сайта появляется модальное окно с регистрацией. Мне нужно немножко другое. 
 [Пример содержимого всплывающего окна](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CZwn7.png). Вот в это окно надо добавить кнопку, которая открывает другое окно с большей информацией.

Comment: Вот смотрите сделаю чуток по другому

Comment: Мне этот код. Я показал как это делается, а код добавляйте сами. Тем более  с картинки. Это сайт фрилансеров. И за бесплатно делать работу за вас никто не собираетя